# Separating audio file in 3 different frequency areas

Tags: matlab, audio, fft, frequency

I apologize in advance, if the title is confusing. Basically, i have a Audio-file, on which I perform a STFT every 50ms. My File is about 11 seconds long (10.8526s), which i have cut off from a soundtrack. Btw, i am not allowed to use the built-in function in Matlab for the STFT. I am aware it is much more easier. Anyway, after i run my code, every 50 ms a STFT is performed and the picture is being plotted. 
Now i want to seperate it in 3 different plots. In the first plot i have the lower frequencies (0-300Hz), in the second plot medium frequencies(300-5kHz) and in the last plot i have high frequencies(5Khz-fs/2). fs=44100 --> Further explanations below in the code. How can i define now the areas?

```
%AUDIO-FILE
%______________________________________________________
[y,fs]=audioread('UnchainMyHeart.wav');
% audioread = Reads Audio file
% y = A vector, which contains the audio signal
% fs = sample rate
% 'UnchainMyHeart' = Audio file
%______________________________________________________


% Paramter for the real-time spectral-analysis
%______________________________________________________
 NFA=2; 
% Every second picture is being plotted
% Don't need every picture
 t_seg=0.05; 
%Length of the audio signal on which is a STFT performed 

fftlen = 4096; 
% Length of the FFT, frequency resolution

 TPF= 300;
 BPF= 5000;
 HPF= 22050;
% Trying to define the frequencies areas
% Isn't working right now

 LOW=((TPF*fftlen)/fs);
 MEDIUM=((BPF*fftlen)/fs);
 HIGH=((HPF*fftlen)/fs);
% Contains the number of FFT points in the frequency 
%_______________________________________________________

 segl =floor(t_seg*fs); 

 windowshift=segl/2; 

 window=hann(segl); 

 window=window.'; 

 si=1; 
% Start Index

 ei=segl; 
% End Index

 AOS= length(y)/windowshift - 1;

 f1=figure;

f=0:1:fftlen-1;
f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;

Ya=zeros(1,fftlen);

n=0;

for m= 1:1:AOS

y_a = y(si:ei);
y_a= y_a.*window;
Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);

n=n+1;
if n==1
  Yres=abs(Ya);
  else
  Yres=Yres+abs(Ya);
end

if n==NFA
  Yres=Yres/NFA;
  n=0;

  drawnow; 
  %Updates the graphical objects which are being plotted every 50ms

figure(f1);
plot(f(1:end/2), 20*log10(abs(Yres(1:end/2))));

ylim([-90 50]);
title('Spektrum of audio signal');
xlabel('f(Hz)');
ylabel('dB');
grid on;

end

si=si+windowshift; 
% Updating Start Index    
ei=ei+windowshift; 
% Updating End index

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to run you code as I do not have your audio file but I will try to explain conceptually, and use pseudo code.

**Frequency brick-wall**

If you just want to separate the frequencies for visual purposes you can just use brick-wall filters.

Perform an `fft` of the full signal. Define a frequency vector.

```
SigFD = fft(signal);
n = length(signal); % number of samples
fs = 44100; % sampling rate
deltaF = fs/n; % frequency resolution
F = [0:floor(n/2)-1, -(floor(n/2)):-1]*deltaF; % frequency vector
```

Slice the signal based on the frequency range that you want.

```
lowF = 0;
highF = 500;
part1Range = abs(F)>lowF&abs(F)<highF;
Fpart1 = F(part1Range);
Sig1FD = SigFD(part1Range);
```

*Note that I am unable to test the code on your waveform so this should be considered more of pseudo code!*